# Forcing a synchronous client side function execute asynchronously or Kill the sync function after sometime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am running a library function on client side which is synchronous in nature which is why once it gets executed it blocks the entire UI thread. I tried wrapping everything in promise but it still doesn't solve the problem which I am assuming is because usually async function in promise is executed somewhere else(i.e either server side or third party API) but this function is getting executed in my browser.

What I want is not not block the browser till this libfunc is execution or maybe kill the libFunc after sometime.

```
function foo(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       try{
         library.libFunc();
         resolve();     
       }catch(e){
         reject(e);
       });

}

function someFunc(){
    foo()
    .then(function(result){
       console.log('hey');
    })
    .catch(function(e)){
     console.error(e);
    });
    $timeout(function(){
         console.log('hey'
    },5000);
}
```

It never prints hey until libFunc() finishes.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. Consider using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to run scripts in background threads.

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg, looks like this might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Web Workers

From the Docs:

> Web Workers is a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface. In addition, they can perform I/O using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (although the `responseXML` and `channel` attributes are always null). Once created, a worker can send messages to the JavaScript code that created it by posting messages to an event handler specified by that code (and vice versa).
>
> If you need to immediately terminate a running worker from the main thread, you can do so by calling the worker's [terminate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) method.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)